# Cómo hacer que mi arreglo guarde la información?

Tags: java, array

Estoy tratando de que mi arreglo guarde la información de las ventas por día para que después me tire: 1. la venta mayor y 2. los días dónde la venta sea más de 500, pero no lo logró.
Agradecerían si me pueden decir en qué estoy fallando para comprender el tema de arreglos

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float totalVentas = 0;
    float mayor500 = 0;
    int posDelMayor = 0;
    int pos500 = 0;

    String[] diaVentas = new String[]{"lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sàbado", "domingo"};

    for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el total de ventas de " + (i + 1) + " en dolares ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        diaVentas[] = sc.nextInt();
        totalVentas += diaVentas[];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {
        if (diaVentas[] > ventas[posDelMayor]) {
            posDelMayor = i + 1;
        } else if (diaVentas[i] > 500[pos500]) {
            pos500 = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deberías repasar el funcionamiento de los arrays/arreglos y cómo se usa la notación con corchetes, algo como `diaVentas[]= sc.nextInt();` no tiene sentido.

Comment: Tu código es poco claro, ¿podrías añadir mas información? por ejemplo de donde salen las variables `ventas`, `posDelMayor` y `pos500`, pero de entrada te puedo decir que te falta indicar el indice de donde estás asignando o comparando valores de tus arrays por ejemplo `diaVentas[i] = sc.nextInt();` o `diaVentas[i] > ventas[posDelMayor]`

Comment: Acabo de copiar todo el código desde el inicio para que lo puedan ver porque tal vez no tiene sentido si sólo copio una parte

Answer (score 0):

En `Java` a diferencia de otros lenguajes de programación como `Python`, no es posible introducir distintos tipos de datos en un mismo arreglo.

En tu caso tu arreglo `diaVentas[]`, es un arreglo de tipo `String`, por lo mismo en la línea que tienes en  `diaVentas[] = sc.nextInt();`, lo que estás haciendo es tratar de ingresar un dato de tipo `int` a un arreglo de `Strings`, lo que te dará error. Esto se arregla recogiendo desde `Scanner` un `String`:

```java
diaVentas[] = sc.next();
```

Además haciendo aquello solo reemplazar el nombre del día, por un número que se recoge en `sc`.

---

Debido a lo anterior, he tomado tu código y lo he cambiado un poco:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dias500 = ""; //String para almacenar los días sobre 500
        int mayorVenta = 0; //tomará el valor de la venta mayor de todas
        String diaMayor = ""; // Tomará el nombre del día con la venta mayor
        //Un array 2d, almacena el día y la venta total de cada día
        String[][] diaVentas = new String[][] {{"Lunes", "0"},
                                               {"Martes", "0"},
                                               {"Miércoles", "0"},
                                               {"Jueves", "0"},
                                               {"Viernes", "0"},
                                               {"Sábado", "0"},
                                               {"Domingo", "0"}};
        //for para rellenar el array
        for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {    
           System.out.println("Ingrese las ventas totales del día  " + diaVentas[i][0]);
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           diaVentas[i][1] = sc.next(); //se almacena el resultado obtenido en el array
        }
        //for para recorrer el array y sacar la venta mayor y
        //los días en que la venta fue mayor a 500
        for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {
            //Para ver las ventas sobre 500 o igual
            if(Integer.parseInt(diaVentas[i][1])>=500){
                dias500 += " - " + diaVentas[i][0];                       
            }
            //obtener la mayor venta
            if(Integer.parseInt(diaVentas[i][1])> mayorVenta){
                mayorVenta = Integer.parseInt(diaVentas[i][1]);
                diaMayor = diaVentas[i][0];
            }
        }
        //salidas
        System.out.println("Días con ventas sobre 500 " +  dias500);
        System.out.println("Mayor venta de la semana " + mayorVenta + " el día " + diaMayor);
    }
```

> Resultado

[image: resultados]

## Explicación del código:

1. He borrado las variables que tenías declaradas al principio, en su lugar, he puesto: `dias500`, que almacena los días que tengan una venta total por encima o igual de 500, `mayorVenta` y `diaMayor`, la primera almacena la venta más alta y la segunda el día correspondiente a la venta más alta.
2. El `array` de tipo `String` que tenías lo cambié a un [array 2D](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/) de esta manera además de poder guardar el nombre del día se podrá guardar el valor de la venta total de cada uno
3. Construí un `for` que se encarga de rellenar los datos de las ventas de cada uno de los días.
4. Utilicé un segundo `for`, el cual se encarga de obtener el valor de la mayor venta y el día en que esta fue.